# Borrar caracteres dentro de un string?

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes estoy intentando hacer un string con una lista que saco de un bucle for y quiero que quede algo como:

termino1, termino2, termino3.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inside.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inside[i].displayCategories == "x")
            {
                finalresutlt += inside[i].xxx+", ";
                
            }
        }
```

Por ahora este codigo me da lo siguiente:

termino1, termino2, termino3,

y lo que quería conseguir es que la ultima coma del bucle se sustituya por un punto.

termino1, termino2, termino3.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: No estoy seguro sobre si habrá un método para esto, pero lo que puedes hacer es recorrer tu string carácter a carácter y guardar la coma de la última posición, luego simplemente reemplaza esta coma por un punto

Comment: Si hay un metodo para esto. podes completar tu ejemplo con el tipo que tiene inside y con algunos datos? esto se hace con string.join

Comment: Simple, agrega un IF y mira si el índice es el último, si es el último, que agregue un punto en lugar de una coma.

Comment: @fredyfx hay alguna palabra clave para saber si el índice es el último? Es que saco los datos de un json que varía por lo tanto el número de índices también. Si no se me ocurre hacer otro bucle con un int que acumule los índices para saber cuantos hay y luego otro para sacar los datos.

Comment: @gbianchi el inside contiene una lista json de strings.

Comment: quiero saber el tipo.. porque si inside es iterable, entonces String.Join hace todo ese trabajo solo.. por algo lo pregunto.. no? o sea, es una List?

Comment: @gbianchi Si. Es un list

Comment: IZulo, si te doy un inside.Count cuyo valor es 3, el índice actual es 2 y habiendo iniciando en 0, ¿crees que ese índice == 2 es el último valor de la lista?

Comment: Puedes usar la función `Substring` para cortarlo, plantear diferente el código o usar `string.Join(", ", inside.Select(e => e.displayCategories))`

Answer (score 1):

Como el último índice no cumplía siempre esta condición "(inside[i].displayCategories == "x")" he creado un bucle para contar los índices que si cumplen esa condición y de este modo he conseguido lo que quería. Se que habrá mil formas de hacerlo mas sencillo pero soy bastante nuevo en este mundillo y mientras me funcione por ahora me conformo. Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda :)

```
for (int o = 0; o < inside.Count; o++)
        {

            if (inside[o].displayCategories == "x")
            {
                contarultimoindice = o;

            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < inside.Count; i++)
        {
            
            if (inside[i].displayCategories == "x")
            {
                if (i == contarultimoindice)
                {
                    finalresutlt += inside[i].itemDesc + ".";
                }
                else
                {
                    finalresutlt += inside[i].itemDesc + ", ";
                }
                
                    
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedws usar substring para cortar el string hasta la ultima coma y luego agregarle el punto

```
for (int i = 0; i < inside.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inside[i].displayCategories == "x")
            {
                finalresutlt += inside[i].xxx+", ";
                
            }
        }

    finalresutlt = finalresutlt.Substring(0, finalresutlt.Length - 2) + "."
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad, todo esto es mucho mas simple si usamos las funciones ya prensentes en el lenguaje.

[String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0#system-string-join(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string)))) es una funcion que en una de sus definiciones, toma un iterable, y le concatena, usando un char como separador.

Por ejemplo, podrias hacer esto:

```
String.Join(",",inside);
```

Pero vamos mas lejos... vos queres tomar solo algunos items de inside. Como es una lista, podemos filtrarla (usando [linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0)) para obtener una nueva lista con solo los elementos que queres:

```
var listafiltrada = inside.Where(x => x.displayCategories == "x");
string final = String.Join(",",listafiltrada);
```

Pero nos falta algo.. un punto al final... entonces, vamos a agregarlo simplemente concatenandolo

```
var listafiltrada = inside.Where(x => x.displayCategories == "x");
string final = String.Join(",",listafiltrada);
final += ".";
```